# Thinning Tomato paste

Tags: tomatoes, condiments, consistency

I have been experimenting with making my own condiments over the paste few weeks and there is one thing I cannot get correct.

The tomato paste has a thicker grainy texture that is really not desirable in a condiment so I was wondering if there is a good way thin out that texture for a more saucy feel.  I am also trying to maintain a strict Paleo diet so using corn syrup or other things like it are not ideal.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think tomato puree or passata might be something for you. It's thinner than tomato paste.
To know for sure whether it fits in your diet or not, you should check the label. Ingredients may vary from brand to brand, but normally, it's just tomatoes.

Comment: +1 for the tomato puree. If you can't find a puree that meets your dietary needs, what about making your own from fresh tomatoes (since they are in season) and then freezing extra for use all year round?